# Delete Javascript generated HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am programming a blackjack game and for each drawn card i create a tag `<img>` to display the card. 
Naturally i have to delete this tag `<img>` after every game, but how can i do this?

Is there a way that I can remove all `<img>` tags within a parent?

Is there something like this: (Pseudecode)

```
div.removeAllChildElemtens()
```

or

```
div.removeChildElements("img");
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can set innerHTML=""

Comment: i dont know how many IMG tags exactly be generated, because the cards differ in every game.. so i need a way to just delete this IMG tags at every new game started...

Comment: append a classname to the images you want to delete later on. so you can use `getElementsByClassName("to-delete")` or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the elements using `document.createElement('img')` then you can keep a reference to them in order to delete them later.

```
var cards = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 52; i++)
{
    var card = document.createElement('img');
    // ... more initialisation of card
    cards.push(card);
}

// later, to remove all

for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
{
    var card = cards[i];
    card.parentElement.removeChild(card);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. With this, it is working fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please, see the `removeChild` usage trick or use the new `remove()` function:

```
var div = document.getElementById("parentDivId");
var images = div.getElementsByTagName('img');

for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    var img = images[i];
    img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
   //OR img.remove() as @Pete TNT pointed-out for modern web-browsers (FF/CH < 23)
}
```

Comment: Isn't `remove()` jQuery?

Comment: ChildNode.remove() is also supported by few modern browsers (FF/CH < 23) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove